# Splitting List<T> based on comma separated property value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given this class:

```
public class Article
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have the following `List<Article>` where some of the articles contain a comma separated name:

```
var list = new List<Article> 
{
    new Article { Name = "Article1, Article2, Article3", Colour = "Red" },
    new Article { Name = "Article4, Article5, Article6", Colour = "Blue" },
}
```

Is there a way, in one `Linq` statement, to get a list where each comma separated name becomes a separate article?

```
var list = new List<Article> 
{
    new Article { Name = "Article1", Colour = "Red" },
    new Article { Name = "Article2", Colour = "Red" },
    new Article { Name = "Article3", Colour = "Red" },
    new Article { Name = "Article4", Colour = "Blue" },
    new Article { Name = "Article5", Colour = "Blue" },
    new Article { Name = "Article6", Colour = "Blue" },
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with `SelectMany`:

```
var res = list.SelectMany(
    art => art.Name.Split(',').Select(n =>
        new Article {
            Name = n.Trim()
        ,   Colour = art.Colour
        }
    )
);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/CjpQCt)

> I was hoping there was a way that would save me newing-up an object since my class [...] has quite a bit more than two properties

Although you cannot avoid `new`-ing altogether, you can improve readability of your code quite a bit by hiding the copying of individual properties inside the `Article`, like this:

```
public class Article {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public Article Rename(string newName) {
        return new Article {
            Name = newName
        //  Copy the remaining attributes
        ,   Colour = this.Colour
        };
    }
}
```

Now your LINQ would look like this:

```
var res = list.SelectMany(art => art.Name.Split(',').Select(n => art.Rename(n.Trim())));
```

This did not remove any code, simply reshuffled some of it. However, placing the copying of `Article`'s properties into `Article` reduces the chance that you wold forget to copy newly added properties.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I came very close to something very much quite like this, but I was hoping there was a way that would save me newing-up an object since my class is a DTO and, as you can imagine, it has quite a bit more than two properties ;)

Comment: @SergiPapaseit That's a fair observation. Although you can't avoid `new` altogether, you could restructure your code for better maintainability.

Comment: Neat approach. I'd upvote you again if I could ;)
What I've finally done is tuck the transformation bit of linq away inside an extension method.

Comment: I think the query syntax would be more natural here: `from article in list from name in article.Name.Split(',') select new Article { Name = name.Trim(), Colour = article.Colour }`.